# Cannot enter the BIOS on a Samsung ATIV Book 2

Tags: windows-8, boot, bios, uefi

I bought a new Samsung ATIV Book 2 NP270E5V-K01AE Notebook.

It was running Windows 8 perfectly. I downloaded and installed Windows 8.1 and after the installation the laptop just restarts automatically continuously.

I am unable to use the Samsung restore function using <kbd>F4</kbd> or enter the BIOS setup using <kbd>F2</kbd>. I also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>. I tried all possible keys but am still unable to enter BIOS.

I removed the HDD from laptop and attached it to another desktop PC. I then formatted the `C:` partition. Then it didn't boot any further, only BIOS appeared. I can enter BIOS and restore default settings now.

Again, after installing a fresh copy of Windows 8 64-bit, I'm unable to enter the BIOS. I repeated the same procedure I did earlier and also tried entering the BIOS without the HDD attached but all my tries failed.

I installed Windows 8 64-bit (Windows in UEFI mode and also convert partition to GUID Partition Table mode). It's running perfectly but only in MBR mode.

Now I want to reinstall Windows in UEFI mode but still unable to enter the BIOS.

Now I would like to upgrade or downgrade the BIOS so I could enter the BIOS with Windows installed. How can I fix it?

Comment: You have several spelling mistakes and it makes it very hard to understand your question.  The first thing you have to do is covert the partition to GPT, in order to even boot in **UEFI** mode.  **The key to access the BIOS on a `Samsung ATIV Book 2` is F10.**

Comment: You will also have to disable Fast Boot.  This is likely your first problem.

Comment: Dear Sir Ramond i understand ! simple i am unable to enter in bios, F2, F10, DEL WINDOW+B, i try my best but Failed

Comment: Contact Samsumg because it's suppose to be f10 so if it's not working then the device is malfunctioning

Answer (score 2):

After days of fighting with a samsung NP270 I found a way to start the system recovery utiliy

1: remove the hard drive from the laptop
2: start the laptop without cd or hard drives
3: wait for the "All boot options are tried. Press [F4] key to recover with factory image using Recovery or any keys for next boot loop iteration." message
4: very carefully connect again the original hard drive and press the F4 key
5: laptop should reboot
6: recovey starts
7: reinstall windows

It worked for me hope this works for you too

Comment: Looks like it's working for me too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on a 6-month-old Samsung NP270E5V which was pre-installed with Windows 8 and [the manual for which](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/604570/Samsung-Np270e5e-K01us.html?page=82#manual) states clearly that the BIOS access key is F2. However, as with the OP, this doesn't work. Nor does it work, as I have tried, with **any of the other Function keys**.

[It seems that there is a serious bug in Samsung laptops](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/22855.html) (I cannot tell you the range, but at least I now know the model in question suffers from it) that seems to stops them from booting or going into an infinite boot loop after a crash dump. No repetitive strain injury bashing of any of the function keys will resolve this.

I removed and looked at the hard drive on another PC and it is fine. I inserted another drive which has a virgin Windows 7 on it and, no doubt due to Secure Boot being selected by default, a message comes up **All boot options are tried. Press [F4] key to recover with factory image using Recovery or any keys for next boot loop iteration.** (no changes made to original Ingrish).

Still with the Win7 hard drive in, I then inserted an Ubuntu 14 x64 USB install SD card as well as a Spotmau ERD USB Flash drive and a Spotmau ERD CD-ROM and hit "any key". The laptop didn't boot from any of them. I finally inserted a factory Windows 7 Ultimate x64 install DVD and, on hitting "any key", the DVD spun and I got the following onscreen: **Secure Boot -- Image failed to verify with ¤ACCESS DENIED¤ -- Press any key to continue**.

So, the BIOS has recognised that something is trying to install but denies access because of Secure Boot. And since I cannot switch off Secure Boot because the BIOS is effectively locked out (the Samsung crash dump EUFI bug), this laptop is going back to the factory.

I hope this answers the question: Yes, the correct BIOS access key for your Samsung NP270E5V is a rapid, repeated F2, but if you find yourself nevertheless locked out of the BIOS, remove the hard drive, back up your data and consider using your laptop's warranty and get the thing replaced. It's a known bug. In a subsequent tweet, the developer who originally discovered the problem pointed out that not even removing the CMOS battery brought the device back to life. So I'm not going to bother, given I've already spent an hour on a laptop that is going to be as broken when I give it back to the customer as when she handed it to me. I'm pretty sure she'll be happier paying for an hour of my time than paying for two hours for the same end result.

Sorry for the long post but I thought it was both worth it and answered the OP's question.

Comment: Yours is the only that explain this behavior so far. Cannot enter BIOS with F2, cannot show startup repair with F4, if a HDD with Windows 8/8.1/10 is installed the OS will say "Starting automatic repair" in a infinite loop. Linux doesn't boot (because of UEFI being enabled). You cannot  disable UEFI because laptop doesn't want to accept the pressing of F2 key. Nothing works. Without HDD installed, laptop is trapped in an infinite loop that shows the text "Press F4 to show repair options" that only remains for 1 second or less and then reboot. Reset BIOS by any mean doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@Ramhound's comment above was perfect, except for one thing – it is <kbd>F4</kbd>, not <kbd>F10</kbd> on a Samsung Ativ Book 4, and you need to be very quick with pressing <kbd>F4</kbd>.

The rest of the comment is accurate. For starters, disable Fast Boot. You will have an option in your BIOS for UEFI boot.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 does not ever completely shut down. to shut down windows 8 go to shutdown icon hold Shift and click shutdown. 
on re boot press F2 or Delete enter bios and turn off UEFI .

Also then you can use F4